# Simple NGINX log file analyzer

Tags: nginx, analytics

I'm looking for a simple tool to analyze my NGINX logs on my macbook.
I want to be able to get some basic stats including bot access and also be able to sort/filter the logs to find out what happened right before the server crashed.

Answer (score 133):

You may try with [GoAccess](http://goaccess.io); free and open source console based. It may output an HTML report too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out goaccess - simple to install (apt-get install goaccess on Debian/Ubuntu) and does quite a lot of nice stuff right on the command line right out of the box. No setup.

Comment: Also installs with `brew install goaccess` on Mac.

Comment: To install on Mac OS X without relying on homebrew, check the goaccess faq [here](https://goaccess.io/faq), specifically the section  _How to install GoAccess from source under OS X El Capitan?_

Comment: with the default NGINX combined format, `goaccess --log-format=COMBINED access.log` or `{ cat access.log; zcat access.log.*.gz; } | goaccess --log-format=COMBINED -` (for all logs) worked well for me.

Answer (score 30):

I've come across [visitors](http://www.hping.org/visitors/).
It's written in C and is pretty fast.

It lacks GoAccess' cool ncurses interface. It only outputs html.
It does the job, though.

It can also output human-readable text reports:

```
visitors access.log | less
```

Answer (score 7):

I will suggest to use logstash and Kibana with following patterns :

for access.log :

```
NGINXACCESS %{IPORHOST:clientip} - %{USERNAME:remote_user} \[%{HTTPDATE:time_local}\] %{QS:request} %{INT:status} %{INT:body_bytes_sent} %{QS:http_referer} %{QS:http_user_agent}
```

for error.log:

```
 NGINXERROR (?<timestamp>%{YEAR}[./-]%{MONTHNUM}[./-]%{MONTHDAY}[- ]%{TIME}) \[%{LOGLEVEL:severity}\] %{POSINT:pid}#%{NUMBER}: %{GREEDYDATA:errormessage}(?:, client: (?<clientip>%{IP}|%{HOSTNAME}))(?:, server: %{IPORHOST:server})(?:, request: %{QS:request})?(?:, host: %{QS:host})?(?:, referrer: \"%{URI:referrer})?
```

Comment: elk stack is the most powerfull solution if well configured.

Comment: but requires a lot of GB and some basic VPS cannot simple run it

Comment: Agreed with you

Answer (score 6):

The request-log-analyzer gem now has Nginx support in the master branch and i'm looking for someone to test it.
http://github.com/wvanbergen/request-log-analyzer.

Comment: can it handle both the NGINX access logs and error logs?

Answer (score 3):

I've now tried [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/), it's a pretty powerful tool and they have a free version as well.

Comment: Wow, it's pretty great! The free version limits you 500MB of new logs per day, which is generous enough.

Comment: I don't know the product yet, but the website feels very confusing to me